# In what directory are the saved games stored?

Tags: sins-of-a-solar-empire

Pretty simple question: where does Sins of a Solar Empire save games?  I'm sharing saves between machines using Windows Live Mesh and I'd like to know where to point it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're saved in:

> C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Ironclad Games\Sins of a Solar Empire\

There is a Save-SinglePlayer and Save-MultiPlayer folder that contains save games from each category.

Comment: Okay, for bonus points, how do you tell Windows Live Mesh to sync that directory between two machines?

Comment: @Axiom sacrifice a goat and pray? :P